# Extract coefficients of all monomials of a multivariate function

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let us consider that I have a multivariate function,

```
f[x_,y_] = a+b*x+c*x*y+d*y^2;
```

and I need an array of all possible coefficients of this function in the basis `{1,x,y,x^2,y^2,x y}`. So my final answer should look like 
`{a,b,0,0,d,c}`. I have tried `CoefficientList`, but it provides only non-zero monomial coefficients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
First @@@ CoefficientRules[{1, x, y, x^2, y^2, x y}, {x, y}] /. 
  CoefficientRules[a + b x + c x y + d y^2, {x, y}] /. {_, _} :> 0
```

> `{a, b, 0, 0, d, c}`

**Update:** You can define a function that takes a list of variables, a list of monomials, and a polynomial and returns the coefficients in the desired order:

```
ClearAll[coefF]
coefF[vars_, basis_, poly_] := First @@@ CoefficientRules[basis, vars] /. 
   CoefficientRules[poly, vars] /. {_, _} :> 0
```

Examples:

```
coefF[{x, y}, {1, x, y, x^2, y^2, x y }, a + b x + c x y + d y^2]
```

> {a, b, 0, 0, d, c}

Using David's suggestion for the list of monomials:

```
coefF[{x, y}, Flatten[Table[x^i y^j, {j, 0, 2}, {i, 0, 2}]], a + b x + c x y + d y^2]
```

> {a, b, 0, 0, c, 0, d, 0, 0}

Comment: kglr may wish to use `Flatten[Table[x^i y^j, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}]]` in his excellent answer, which will generalize to higher order naturally.

Comment: @David, good suggestion, thank you. I wanted to stick with the list of monomials in OP's "basis", to get the desired output, `{a, b, 0, 0, d, c}`.